# Trigger shell script execution by a POST request

Tags: bash, webserver, centos-7, url

There is a CentOS 7 machine and a BASH script in it.

This script is being executed either by Cron scheduler or manually when I log on to the server via SSH.

I would like to trigger script execution also by sending a POST request to a web server on the same machine (without having to log on). How to do this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Common gateway Interface (CGI) is one.  Here is a simple [guide](https://linuxconfig.org/simple-cgi-and-apache-examples-on-ubuntu-linux) that shows you to execute a Bash script, as well as other languages, through the browser.

Some languages allow you to directly call the OS to run a program or script.  For example PHP has [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Just a note:  While executing local scripts and commands from a browser is not uncommon, there are always risks involved.  Make sure you limit access to the webpage as needed, as web based access to the OS has risks.

Comment: Thank you. I would like only to trigger script executiion per web. No one intends that the web server should actually run the script as a child process. This script is harmless. If there is nothing to do, it does nothing.